# Limit of shifted ratios

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $f$ a be a strictly positive function defined in the positive reals. Additionally suppose that for any $\delta > 0$ we have, as
$t \to \infty$,
$$ e^{-t^{1+\delta}} \ll f(t) \ll e^{t^{1+\delta}}$$
where we have used "Hardy's notation": $f(t) \ll g(t) \Leftrightarrow f(t) = o(g(t))$.

It is true then that for any $u \geq 0$ the limit
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(u+t)}{f(t)} $$
exists and is strictly positive?

The exponential, power and logarithmic cases are true, that is what led me to pose the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should we assume that $f$ is continuous or differentiable? I think that some not-so-useful counterexamples could be constructed using discontinuous functions, like the Dirichlet function.

Comment: @ChristianOudard Yes, you can assume continuity. I am not looking for pathological cases :) .